# Update 2 or More Columns in MySQL With One Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to update 2 or more rows on my MySQL with one code, this what I got now.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET auth='yes' AND authtime='$time' WHERE username='$_GET[username]'");
```

the auth='yes' is 0 for some reason and authtime'$time' hasn't change from no to 1368135045

Can anyone help?

Comment: Is it 2 or more *tables* or *rows* ...!?

Comment: @Ravinder: It's two _columns_.

Comment: [`Lovely...`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: @spencer7593: That part I could understand much earlier. I wanted to get confirm, if OP missed something to post.

Answer (score 1):

To change the value of more than one column, use a comma delimiter between the column assignments, like this:

```
UPDATE mytab SET col1 = val , col2 = val WHERE ...
                            ^
                            +----- comma here
```

Your query is valid syntax, and it's executing successfully.
But your query is of the form:

```
UPDATE users SET auth = (expression) WHERE username='$_GET[username]'
```

The problem is that query has an `AND` keyword where you want a comma delimiter.

What's happening is MySQL is reading that `AND` as part of the expression being assigned to the column `auth`.  MySQL is evaluating this expression:

```
'yes' AND authtime='$time'
```

MySQL is evaluating that as a boolean expression, and taking the result of the boolean expression (which is FALSE), and assigning that result to column `auth`. (And that's the only column your statement is assigning a value to.)

Answer (score 1):

try this ,will work surely

```
UPDATE users SET auth='yes' ,  authtime='$time' WHERE username='$_GET[username]'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have syntax error in `UPDATE`.

Change:

```
UPDATE users SET auth='yes' AND authtime='$time' WHERE username='$_GET[username]'
```

To:

```
UPDATE users SET auth='yes', authtime='$time' WHERE username='$_GET[username]'
```